# Webpack 5 migration: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm migrating a legacy application to webpack 5 and I have this error when I access a view that is using webpack dynamic import and React.lazy

`

```
const DynamicComponent = React.lazy(() =>
  import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "ComponentChunkName" */ 'client/component/path'
  )
);
```

`

Our existing webpack config is:

`

```
optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'deterministic',
    splitChunks: {
      automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
      name: false,
      cacheGroups: {
        vendorsInitial: {
          enforce: true,
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: 10,
          name: 'vendorsInitial',
          chunks: (chunk) => !/^(admin|public)$/.test(chunk.name) && entryKeys.includes(chunk.name),
        },
        vendorsAsync: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

`

the errors is fixed if we add `

```
usedExports: false,
```

`
but we are trying to clean up the as recommended in the [webpack migration document](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#clean-up-configuration)

I tried to search similar errors but I can't find an explanation as to why the unusedExports value solves the problem or how to fix the root cause.